# With JSON logs can I merge multiple values under a single key

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-logging

I want to merge multiple values under a single JSON key while logging it to the console.

Here is a code snippet

```py
import logging
from pythonjsonlogger import jsonlogger


LOG_FORMAT = '%(asctime)s %(levelname)s %(filename)s %(funcName)s %(threadName) %(message)'

logformatter = jsonlogger.JsonFormatter(LOG_FORMAT)
stdloghandler.setFormatter(logformatter)
logger.addHandler(stdloghandler)
```

**Generated Output:**

```
{"asctime": "2022-01-06 12:21:03,878", "levelname": "DEBUG", "filename": "xyz.py", "funcName": "abc", "threadName": "MainThread", "message": "..............."}
```

**Expected output:**

I want to merge filename,funcName,threadName under one key

Something like this

```
{"asctime": "2022-01-06 12:21:03,878", "levelname": "DEBUG", "file": "xyz.py:abc:MainThread", "message": "..............."}
```

```
"file": "xyz.py:abc:MainThread"
```

I didn't find any examples which did this nor any documents.
Reference: https://pypi.org/project/python-json-logger/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation you linked [here](https://pypi.org/project/python-json-logger/#:%7E:text=logger.addHandler(logHandler)-,customizing%20fields,-The%20fmt%20parser) shows how to create a custom format. You can also see the [attributes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logrecord-attributes) of the `LogRecord` that is passed in to the function call.

```
class CustomJsonFormatter(jsonlogger.JsonFormatter):
    def add_fields(self, log_record, record, message_dict):
        super(CustomJsonFormatter, self).add_fields(log_record, record, message_dict)

        custom_msg = f"{record.filename}:{record.funcName}:{record.threadName}"
        log_record["file"] = custom_msg

formatter = CustomJsonFormatter('%(asctime)s %(levelname)s %(file)s %(message)')
```